# Android - Computations in background

Tags: android, service

First question:
I know that in the Activities only view content should be implemented but is it usual to start an own service for each longer computation process?

Second question:
And the communication with the service is really extensive in code. If you want to invoke a method on the service you have to realize the hole IPC-mechanism?? Or is it also possible to invoke methods on local services without using the AIDL-files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on task you want to perform consider using `AsyncTask` or `IntentService`. Using regular `Service` should rather not suit your needs best here.

If you use regular `Service` you can easily pass your data or arguments or whatever in `Intent`. You do not need any IPC for this.

Comment: can I also pass objects in Intents?

Comment: And why is it better to use asyncTask or service than creating a normal java thread that do the computations in background?

Comment: @TobiWeißhaar AsyncTask is helper class but when threading on Android you may find it more suitable to use than 'direct' Java threads. I believe you can do what you want with Java threads as well, but AsyncTask should simplify the thing. If you are not sure, give AsyncTask a try: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: @TobiWeißhaar yes, you can pass `Parcelable` objects with no problem

Answer (score 1):

First question: you can start an AsynTask for longer computation process, service are generally used for action when application on background.

Second question: you can call any Method on your service, the use of idle make your services available for multiple applications, witch is not the case of a simple services, also, sample services runs on the same application process as your activities, witch is not the case of idle service.